# Scroll down and up in UIScrollVIew Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to scroll up and down in my page without using AutoLayout in Xcode. How do I make the scrolling work?

I want to show the second question label and text and add other labels and fields. But I can't scroll to see how they look after building the project

This is the viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo2.jpg"];
self.myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.myImageView.image = bg;
self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.myImageView.center = self.view.center;
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.myImageView];



CGRect scrollViewRect = self.view.bounds;
self.myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewRect];
self.myScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.myScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.myScrollView.frame.size.width + 100, self.myScrollView.frame.size.height + 100);
[self.view addSubview:self.myScrollView];


float width = CGRectGetWidth(self.myScrollView.frame);
float height = CGRectGetHeight(self.myScrollView.frame);
float newPosition = self.myScrollView.contentOffset.y+height;
CGRect toVisible = CGRectMake(newPosition, 0, width, height);

[self.myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:toVisible animated:YES];

//FirstNameLabel
CGRect labelFirst = CGRectMake(10, 100, 100, 30);
self.firstnamelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFirst];
self.firstnamelabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f];
self.firstnamelabel.text = @"First Name : ";

//FirstNameField
CGRect firsttextField = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 30);
self.firstnametext = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:firsttextField];
self.firstnametext.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;


//LastNameLabel
CGRect labelLast = CGRectMake(10, 150, 100, 30);
self.lastnamelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelLast];
self.lastnamelabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f];
self.lastnamelabel.text = @"Last Name : ";

//LastNameTextField
CGRect lasttextField = CGRectMake(100, 150, 200, 30);
self.lastnametext = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:lasttextField];
self.lastnametext.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

//DateLabel
CGRect labeldate = CGRectMake(10, 190, 100, 30);
self.DateOfBirthLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labeldate];
self.DateOfBirthLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f];
self.DateOfBirthLabel.text = @"Date Of Birth: ";

//DatePicker
CGRect datepickersize=CGRectMake(10, 210, 300, 150);
self.datepicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:datepickersize];
NSDate *date= self.datepicker.date;
self.datepicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;

//Email
CGRect labelemail = CGRectMake(30, 370, 100, 30);
self.emaillabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelemail];
self.emaillabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f];
self.emaillabel.text = @"Email : ";

//EmailText
CGRect emailtextField = CGRectMake(100, 370, 200, 30);
self.emailtext = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:emailtextField];
self.emailtext.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

//PasswordLabel
CGRect labelpassword = CGRectMake(10, 410, 100, 30);
self.passwordlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelpassword];
self.passwordlabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f];
self.passwordlabel.text = @"Password : ";

//PasswordText
CGRect passwordtextField = CGRectMake(100, 410, 180, 30);
self.passwordtext = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:passwordtextField];
self.passwordtext.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
self.passwordtext.secureTextEntry = true;

//eyebutton
UIImage *eye = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye.png"];
self.eyebutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.eyebutton.frame = CGRectMake(290, 415, 20, 20);
[self.eyebutton setImage:eye forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.eyebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

[self.eyebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpInside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

```
//FirstQuetionLabel
CGRect labelfq = CGRectMake(10, 450, 300, 20);
self.firstQuestlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelfq];
self.firstQuestlabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
self.firstQuestlabel.text = @"Question 1: In which city you were born in?";

//FirstQuestionTextField
CGRect fqtextField = CGRectMake(10, 470, 240, 30);
self.firstQuestionText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:fqtextField];
self.firstQuestionText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

//SecondQuestionLabel
CGRect labelsq = CGRectMake(10, 500, 300, 30);
self.secondQuestLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelsq];
self.secondQuestLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0f];
self.secondQuestLabel.text = @"Question 2: What is your mother's \rmiddle name?";

//SecondQuestionTextField
CGRect sqtextField = CGRectMake(10, 630, 240, 30);
self.secondQuestionText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:sqtextField];
self.secondQuestionText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;



[self.view addSubview:self.eyebutton];
[self.view addSubview:self.firstnamelabel];
[self.view addSubview:self.firstnametext];
[self.view addSubview:self.lastnamelabel];
[self.view addSubview:self.lastnametext];
[self.view addSubview:self.DateOfBirthLabel];
[self.view addSubview:self.datepicker];
[self.view addSubview:self.emaillabel];
[self.view addSubview:self.emailtext];
[self.view addSubview:self.passwordlabel];
[self.view addSubview:self.passwordtext];
[self.view addSubview:self.firstQuestlabel];
[self.view addSubview:self.firstQuestionText];
[self.view addSubview:self.secondQuestLabel];
[self.view addSubview:self.secondQuestionText];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, scrolling may not be enabled because you have not set the contentSize property of the scroll view.  To set allow scrolling, the contentSize needs to be set to be larger than the frame of the scroll view.

An example in objective-c would be:

`self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.myScrollView.frame.size.width + 20, self.myScrollView.frame.size.height + 20);`

**Updated for edited question**

Any views you want to be scrollable within your scroll view need to be added as a subview on the scrollView i.e

`[self.myScrollView addSubview: myLabel]; //do for all views that you want to be scrollable in the scrollView`

Then you need find the sum height of all the views contained in your scroll view i.e

`CGFloat sumHeight = myLabel1.frame.size.height + myView2.frame.size.height; //etc do for all views you want in your scrollView`

then set it to be your contentSize ie

```
self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.myScrollView.frame.size.width, sumHeight);
```

Comment: so if I'm trying the code on iphone 5 how much should be the size? and aslo I just to need to add it and it will work?

Comment: @FaysalSabbagh The `contentSize` is the size of the content you are putting in the scroll view.

Comment: @FaysalSabbagh the size should be the sum height(or width depending on whether horizontal scrolling is enabled) of all of the objects contained in your scroll view.  and yes, assuming the sum is larger than the frame of your scroll view

Comment: I've tried to increase the height  and width but it did not show the content at the end of the page

Comment: I've updated my question so you can make it clear @CharltonProvatas

Comment: @CharltonProvatas still it's not scrolling

Comment: @FaysalSabbagh try myScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true;

Comment: I changed to storyboard and it worked. Thank you for your help @CharltonProvatas

Comment: @FaysalSabbagh glad it worked! Can you mark my answer as the correct answer? thank you!